# Adding table of contents to title page bottom right corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, titles

I want to make the frontpage of a report after a specific style, as can be seen in the figure below.

The table of contents of this report style is located on the title page as well (these reports are never too long, so the TOC will always fit). I know that it is possible to put the TOC on the front page, but I can't figure out how to put it onll on a specific section of the page. Additionally, I'd like to have the TOC always to be a set distance from the bottom, and grow up with every new added entry (in Word this currently has to be done manually for a report, which makes it slightly inconsistent).

[image: frontpage design]

Below the MWE can be seen, and below that is the output (obviously colours and fonts need to be adjusted). If you have any helpful tips for me, I'd be happy to hear it (I especially dislike using `\\` for the new line of the subtitle, but the subtitle will usually be longer than the title so I can't set a fixed width for the node).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor = west, inner sep = 0 pt] at (current page.west) {\includegraphics[height = \paperheight]{polar_frontpage.png}};
    \filldraw[blue] ([xshift = -2.7 cm] current page.north) -- ([xshift = -2.7 cm] current page.south) -- (current page.south east) -- (current page.north east);
    \filldraw[white] ([xshift = -2.8 cm] current page.north) -- ([xshift = -2.8 cm] current page.south) -- ([xshift = -2.2 cm] current page.south) -- ([xshift = -2.2 cm] current page.north);
    \node[anchor = north, inner sep = 0 pt] (logo) at ([xshift = -2.5 cm, yshift = -3 cm] current page.north) {\includegraphics[height = 8 cm]{logo.png}};
    \node[anchor = west, align = left] (title) at ([xshift = 5 cm] logo) {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont title \\ \fontsize{25}{60}\selectfont subtitle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe output]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that `align` turns the node into a `tabular`, while `text width` turns it into a `\parbox`.  You can put `\tableofcontents` into a `\parbox`.

Comment: Please replace images we don't all have with images we do (e.g. `mwe` package images, there's a tiger somewhere) or use `demo` or a filled node or whatever. Also add some sections or whatever so there's a table of contents for people to put somewhere.

Comment: If you use @JohnKormylo 's suggestion, you can position the node with, for example, `\node [above left=50pt of current page.south and 40pt of current page.east,anchor=base east] {<table of contents>};` or similar if you use the `positioning` library.